# Use app without google play?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to develop an app for my class. Can that app work on my friends aka class mates device without uploading it on the google play.If possible then how?

Comment: You can manually install apps by transferring the APK to the target device and then simply install it by tapping on it using a file manager.

Comment: @GiantTree please also suggest me how to develop a chat room or a group chat room app.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you developing an app. By the way, Android.SE is for Android *users* not developers. Once you got something, you may ask StackOverflow.SE for further help (make sure to make a high quality question).

Comment: @shubhankar I'm sorry, but that doesnt sound like you knoe much about Android Apps. For developing one, you need to know Java good, and knoe the Android Lifecycle and APIs especially if the app is for someone else. Do you know that? If not, throw the project over. Take a few months to learn the requirements and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is Possible.

I think you are developing your app using Android Studio. In Android Studio go to the option **Build -> Build APK** for building your app. Then you can share your app with your friends. But ***Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed.*** So you need to sign your app.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) is a tutorial for building signed app. Then Click on **Build -> Build signed APK** for building your app.

Comment: It is not that much required, you can just use the Android Studio default certificate and it works (although the guys installing it have to enable apps from unknown sources)

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to develop an app for my class. Can that app work on my friends (a.k.a. classmates) device without uploading it on Google Play (Store)?*

Short answer, Yes.

Upon development of your Android App, you may choose to [export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16622843/4625829) it as an APK, distribute it to your desired users, and have them install it directly. Do make sure that *Installing from [Unknown Sources](http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/forum/enable-unknown-sources-android-install-apps-outside-play-store-0150603/)* is **enabled**.

---

Regarding the development of a chat app mentioned in the comments, I support what @GiantTree mentions that you should post that type of questions in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

With that said, when you are still planning on developing the app (*presuming that you already know some dev knowledge when it comes to Android*), I suggest you follow this [Firebase Code Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0).

Answer (score 0):

yes

Android Studio can make signed apk file.
Make your apk file, copy file to sdcard in your phone, and install.